# Navigating with React router without using links

Tags: reactjs, frontend, react-router

I'm using react-router to build a simple application. I can't use browserHistory approach, so, I'm using the hashHistory approach. However, I'm stucked in a point. How can I do a function 'clickHandler' for a submit form, in order to land on another route?

Here is a snippet:

```
onSubmit: function() {
    //go to some route here...
},
render: function() {
    return(
        <button onClick={this.onSubmit} >Submit</button>
   )
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try the following:

```
import { hashHistory } from 'react-router';

onSubmit: function() {
   hashHistory.push('/foo');
},
```

You can see the full `history` API here:
https://github.com/ReactJSTraining/history

Comment: Hey @ctrlplusb, thanks for the anwser. Simple and efficient :)